# Creating dictionary from lists without overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from 3 lists and I'm having trouble with the values being overwritten.

My lists look like this:

```
hosts = ["Host1", "Host2" ...]
uptime = ["50", "60" ...]
downtime = ["50", "40" ...]
```

I need a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{"availability": [{"Host": "Host1", "Uptime": "50", "Downtime": "50"}, {"Host": "Host2", "Uptime": "60", "Downtime": "40"}]}
```

Here's my code:

```
availability_json = {"availability": {}}

for x in range(len(hosts)):
  availability_json["availability"]["Host"] = hosts[x]
  availability_json["availability"]["Uptime"] = uptime[x]
  availability_json["availability"]["Downtime"] = downtime[x]
```

When I run it only the final list is included. I've also tried with dict comprehension with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is:

```
availability_json = {
    "availability": [
        {"Host": host, "Uptime": up, "Downtime": down}
        for host, up, down in zip(hosts, uptime, downtime)
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you want to collect *multiple* instances of "availability", but you created a data structure that can hold only *one* of them.

You need a **list**. You even acknowledged this yourself,

> I need a dictionary that looks like this:
>
> ```
> {"availability": [{...}, {...}]}
> ```

where `[ ... ]` is the list. But in your code, you didn't create a list.

The adjustments you need to make in your code are:

1. initialize a dictionary containing a list, instead of a dictionary containing a dictionary
2. in every iteration of the loop, create a **new** "availability" dictionary (instead of reusing the same one each time), and **append** it to the list

```
availability_json = {"availability": []}  # 1.

for x in range(len(hosts)):
  a = {}  # 2.
  a["Host"] = hosts[x]
  a["Uptime"] = uptime[x]
  a["Downtime"] = downtime[x]
  availability_json["availability"].append(a)
```

Of course, Python allows you to write the same more succinctly, as shown in [orlp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68080422/4621513).